# What's the meaning of "due cause"?

Tags: phrase-meaning, word-meaning

This is the definition of *choke up* from Collins Dictionary:

> *(informal) usually passive* to overcome (a person) with emotion, esp without due cause

What does *due cause* in the definition mean? I've looked up the word *due*, but there isn't a definition that seems appropriate to the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With all due respect, I just Googled *define "due cause"* and went to [the first dictionary definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/due), where it says...

> **due** adj. 4: *Meeting special requirements; sufficient: "We have **due cause** to honor them".*

If that's not clear, the preceding definition #3 says *In accord with right, convention, or courtesy; **appropriate***. And in the same dictionary you'll find [**cause**](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cause) defined as *grounds for action; motive; **justification***.

So you could paraphrase ***due cause*** as ***appropriate justification***. Note that it's often used in legal contexts, so "appropriate" in this expression usually means *right and proper, **according to law***.